# Javascript Summation

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create an autosummation tool that will not count blank cells.  Currently it's just counting 1, but it will count more later. This just returns NaN for any number entry.

```
var _num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
var _sum  = document.getElementById('sum');

_num1.onblur = function summation(){
    _sum.value = 0;
    _sum.value = (parseInt(_sum.value,10) + (isNaN(_num1) ? 0 : _num1.value));
};
```

HTML

```
Num 1: <input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" value=""><br/>
Sum:  <input type="text" id="sum"  name="sum" value="">
```

Comment: 1. Why do you use `_sum.value` after you have set it to 0? 2. You pass a DOM element to `isNaN()`.

Comment: What do you think the problem is? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You know, I'm not 100% sure what I was doing wrong.  I'm not as familiar with Javascript as I would like to be.  But thanks to some help on here I did get a working system.  Here's the final product:  http://jsfiddle.net/bhenne22/sPA9h/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var _num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
var _sum  = document.getElementById('sum');

_num1.onblur = function summation(){
    _sum.value = 0;

    var num1 = parseInt(_num1.value, 10);
    _sum.value = isNaN(num1) ? '0' : num1;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response!  This worked instantly.  I further modified it to accommodate my need for additional fields and is working just the way I want it to now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var num1Val = parseInt(_num1.value, 10);

_sum.value = (parseInt(_sum.value,10) + (isNaN(_num1Val) ? 0 : num1Val ));
```

Answer (score 0):

@ComFreek already commented on your mistakes. To make your script working, you should use a numeric variable for the sum that is

- in the outer scope (not in the event handler)
- updated every time you add something
- and then outputted to your input element

```
var numEl = document.getElementById('num1');
var sumEl  = document.getElementById('sum');
var sum = 0; // declare

_num1.onblur = function summation(){
    var num = parseInt(numEl.value,10); // parse
    if (!isNaN(num)) { // validate
        sum += num; // update
        sumEl.value = sum; // output
    }
};
```